# Keras weight of a model bigger than expected

Tags: keras

I am fine tunig the inception v3 model on cifar10 dataset. After saving it, the size of the model is 175 Mo, before the training it is about 90 Mo so I am wondering why the fine tuned model is bigger ? When I look the number of parameters of the two models it is almost the same.

Original model :
Total params: 23,851,784
Trainable params: 23,817,352
Non-trainable params: 34,432

Fine tuned model :
Total params: 21,823,274
Trainable params: 21,788,842
Non-trainable params: 34,432

Does anyone have an idea about this ?
To save the model, I use the function ModelCheckpoint in a callback inside the fit generator function.

```
checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint(output+'-{epoch:02d}.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, period=checkpoint)
callbacks_list = [callback_tensorboard, checkpoints]

# train 
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=step_train,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=test_generator,
      validation_steps=step_test,
      callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `ModelCheckpoint` saves everything about a model, including the following:

- Model architecture
- Weights
- Training configuration like optimizer and loss function
- The state of the optimizer, so you can resume training directly from a checkpoint.

If you use an optimizer that keeps state, like ADAM or RMSProp, where a running average is kept for each parameter, then this optimizer state is also saved into the HDF5 file, increasing the final file size by a factor defined by the optimizer.

An easy solution is to either use `model.save_weights` manually to only save the weights, or to set the `save_weights_only` parameter to True in your instance of `ModelCheckpoint`.

Comment: Is by saying , "The state of the optimizer, so you can resume training directly from a checkpoint" Do you mean saving the exponentially weighted moving average in a middle of epoch ? I mean I don't understand why to save the model while training if we can save it once before start the train. If I want to resume training I just have to start training again with the weights from the last finished epoch .  So  the save_weights_only in my opinion is not useful ? it should be always True, I don't really can find case where I would like to save the model while training ?

Comment: @StavBodik Its not in the middle of an epoch, it is usually at the end of one. If you don't start with saved moving averages, then training might be unstable or diverge.

Comment: But the weights are saved anyway, This is one of the most important feature of this checkpoint , why I should also save the model while training? Model by definition is something constant its not changing during the train .

Comment: @StavBodik Because then its easier to load the model from the checkpoint directly, its a one line in Keras with load_model.

Comment: Easier ? I am using same function from keras to load the model which was saved before the training progress started?

Comment: @StavBodik Yeah but then you only need one line to do everything, not two. Its just a matter of convenience.

Comment: I am loading it using one line using keras , I don't understand .

Comment: if use_multi_gpu:
        model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = NUM_OF_GPUS)
            if load_weights:
                model.load_weights(weights_to_load_path, by_name=True)   The model loaded here...saved once before training started .

Comment: @StavBodik One line to load both model and weights. If you have more questions, then you should ask your own question, not discuss it in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162718/discussion-between-stav-bodik-and-matias-valdenegro).

Comment: Your right , I did that yesterday : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139494/tensorflow-keras-modelcheckpoint-saving-model-while-training-why .